# Add options to <select> based on value of another <select>

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I am working on a form that requires a  drop-down menu to be populated based on the value of another  that is completed by the user first.

The two selects are "subject" and "topic". When the subject is chosen, the "topic" drop-down menu should contain all of the topics within that subject. E.g. for "maths" subject "topic" should show algebra, shape etc.

How can I achieve this? The values for both selects are done in PHP. For the first select, it is a simple task of using a for loop to populaate the select but it seems as though JavaScript must be used for the second. How shall I go about this?

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Answer (score 0):

Assume that, your first `select` has 2 `option`s:

```
<option value="math">math</option> 
<option value="english">english</option>
```

So, you can load second `select`'s `option` something like this:

```
<option value="math-a">math-a</option>
<option value="math-b">math-b</option>
<option value="english-a">english-a</option>
<option value="english-b">english-a</option>
```

where **a** & **b** is representing different **topic**. You can initially hide the second `select`'s `option` using **jQUery** or **CSS**.

Then, just use **jQuery** to show specific `option` based on first `select` like this:

```
$('#sub').change(function(){
    $('#topic option').css('display', 'none');
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value){
        $('#topic option').each(function(){
            var topic = $(this).val();
            topic = topic.split('-');
            topic = topic[0];
            if(value == topic){
                $(this).css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6gf4mhk/1/)**.

Hope this will works!